# In one column I am getting years ex.2022 i want to load data as 2022-23 if year is 2021 I want to make it as 2021-2022 in pyspark and python

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

In one column I am getting years ex.2022 i want to load data as 2022-23 if year is 2021 I want to make it as 2021-22 in pyspark and python.How can it be done

Answer (score 1):

You can add as 1 value to the `year` value.

```
df =spark.createDataFrame([(2022,),(2021,)],['year'])
df.withColumn("year_add", concat_ws("-",col("year"),col("year")+1)).show(10,False)
#+----+---------+
#|year|year_add |
#+----+---------+
#|2022|2022-2023|
#|2021|2021-2022|
#+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame

```
+----+
|year|
+----+
|2020|
|2021|
|2022|
|2023|
+----+
```

Try this

```
df \
.withColumn("period", concat(col("year"), lit("-"), (col("year")+1).substr(3, 2))) \
.show(10,False)
```

Output

```
+----+-------+
|year|period |
+----+-------+
|2020|2020-21|
|2021|2021-22|
|2022|2022-23|
|2023|2023-24|
+----+-------+
```